# Можно ли добавить часы в new Date()?

Tags: javascript

Допустим, у меня есть 2000 часов, и мне надо, чтоб показывало типа 2000:59:00, можно ли как-то закинуть в пустой `new Date()` и сделать отсчет назад с каждой секундой с `setInterval`?

Comment: класс Date плохо приспособлен для интервалов

Comment: Ну мне только надо взять с Date часи, а уже розделить например 3000 часов на час-минуту-секунду

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такому таймеру не нужны даты - нужно перевести часы в секунды и раз в секунду запускать функцию, которая будет отнимать секунду и раскладывать оставшиеся секунды на `час:минута:секунда`

```js
let timeout;

runTimer(2);

function runTimer(hours = 1) {
  if (timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
  
  let fn;
  fn = (seconds) => {
    const h = Math.trunc(seconds / 3600);
    const s = seconds % 60;
    const m = ((seconds - s) % 3600) / 60;

    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = [
      h,
      `${m}`.padStart(2, 0),
      `${s}`.padStart(2, 0)
    ].join(':');

    if (seconds > 0) {
      timeout = setTimeout(() => fn(seconds - 1), 1000);
    }
  };
  fn(hours * 60 * 60);
}
```

```html
<p>Допустим, у меня есть 2000 часов, и мне надо, чтоб показывало типа 2000:59:00, можно ли как-то закинуть в пустой new Date() и сделать отсчет назад с каждой секундой с setInterval?</p>

<p id="timer"></p>
```